# I can't make changes to the database when I click the button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

First of all, my code is as follows:

`Index.cshtml`:

```
@using ToDoListApp.Models
@model List<TodoTable>

<br />
<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-dark text-white">All Tasks</div>
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Task</th>
            <th scope="col">Urgent</th>
            <th scope="col">Done</th>
            <th scope="col">Transactions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model) {
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">@item.Id</th>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
                <td>@(item.Urgent ? "Yes" : "No")</td>
                <td>@(item.Done ? "Yes" : "No")</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Transactions
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="TransactionsMenu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/Urgent/@item.Id">@(item.Urgent ? "Unurgent" : "Urgent")</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">@(item.Done ? "Undone" : "Done")</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Urgent(int id)
{
    var Task = db.TodoTables.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
    return View("Index", id);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Urgent(TodoTable t)
{
    var Task = db.TodoTables.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == t.Id);
    Task.Urgent = !t.Urgent;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

If the image is:

[image]

After pressing the `Urgent` button in the Drop down menu, if it will do the opposite of the `Urgent` value in the database. So for example if the value is `True` it will set `False`. If it is `False`, it will set `True`.

I put my codes above. If the problem is, when I access the page, I get the error "*This page could not be found*".

[image]

Why could this be? How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Hi @Emir Bolat, how is your controller like? If you use asp.net core mvc and use the default route template, the correct url should be: `ControllerName/ActionName/id`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the id as a query-string parameter:

> https://localhost:7234/Urgent?id=6

So you have to change the `href` attribute to:

```
href="/Urgent?id=@item.Id"
```

If instead you want to pass the id as a route parameter:

> https://localhost:7234/Urgent/6

Then you should change the `[HttpGet]` attribute of your action to `[HttpGet("{id:int}")]`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Hello. I did what you said but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: I suggested two different approaches. Which one you tried? Do you still get error 404 - "This page could not be found"?